# Showing protocol specific mini icons for Jabber/XMPP gateway contacts

Tags: gateway, jabber, xmpp, empathy

Since a short while I'm using Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot (11.10) with gnome-shell (Gnome 3) and I'm trying to get accustomed to the default Empathy Instant Messaging client.

I'm using a gateway service on the side of my Jabber/XMPP server to communicate with lots of contacts over proprietary networks like ICQ or MSN. So I don't use Empathy's native support for ICQ and MSN, and I don't want to change back to using such a thing for various reasons.

One thing that annoys me is that Empathy does not make it clear to me that these contacts are from another instant messaging network. If I enable the View > Show Protocols option they are all recognized as Jabber/XMPP contacts.

Although I perfectly understand why that happens, I would like to be able to change this behavior to make Empathy mark these contacts correctly. Is there a configuration option or a plugin for this? Or may this feature still be in development and will be available later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to do this at present. Gabble, the backend used for XMPP, doesn't expose any information that Empathy could use to determine which protocol these contacts are really on.

If you were interested in developing support for this functionality, the information could perhaps be exposed using the [ContactInfo](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/spec/Connection_Interface_Contact_Info.html) API.